# Is it safe/good to store a Mavic Mini 2 LiPo battery at ~18% for an unplanned next flight?

Tags: lipo-batteries, battery-safety, charging, dji-mini-2

They say it is best to store at ~60% but I personally don't want to spend CC for charging it first and then discharging my battery.

Note: someone said, I can just charge the battery and unplug the battery individually one by one when it reaches 60% since the charging hub will charge the battery sequentially one by one, but it is safe tho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

18% should be safe for a few weeks.

Lipos self-discharge at 1-2% per month, and 15% is about as low as you want to go, so you don't have much safety margin. If you were to leave it for 6 months or a year, it could discharge to the point where permanent damage occurs.

60% is recommended because it's low enough to avoid "storing while fully charged" and allows for a year or two of self-discharge, and can be topped up quite quickly. It's not an exact number. A 30% charge could be safely stored for 6 months, and possibly a year, depending exactly how much it self-discharges.

I've no idea if the battery management chip in the DJI batteries draws any power, but it might. In which case the self-discharge rate might be quite a bit higher.

Yes, it's safe to remove a battery from the charger before it's finished.

Comment: thankyou, so specific answer, that answers all of my question.